# Dates manipulation with moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, react-datetime

I receive the following date from the server:

`"2018-11-21 07:00:00 UTC"`

Then, I convert it using `userTimzone` variable (since I wish the editor would use the user timezone):

`dateOfAction: moment(dateOfLoss, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z').tz(userTimzone).unix()`, So `dateOfAction` is `1542776400`. That is: `Wednesday, November 21, 2018 5:00:00 AM` - and so far so good. That is the dateOfAction in UTC with after right offset

I'm using `react-datetime` as the calendar the edit the date, using UTC.
When performing the `save` action, **without** touching the date, the calendar output is still `1542783600`, but I wish to be `1542783600` - i.e the same value as in the beginning, reverting the offset at the other direction.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Moment doesn't map the `Z` token to the string `"UTC"`.  Since you're parsing in local mode, you are actually getting a moment based on the local computer's time zone rather than UTC.  Thus, change the first part of your code to:

  ```
  moment.utc(dateOfLoss, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm [UTC]')
  ```

  The brackets are to treat UTC as a literal string, which isn't strictly required so you can omit it if you like and the result will be the same.

  ```
  moment.utc(dateOfLoss, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
  ```
- There's no need to call `.tz(userTimezone)` if you're just going to call `.unix()` subsequently.  Unix timestamps are always UTC based.  Though it's not clear why you're asking for a Unix timestamp, as react-datetime doesn't need one.
- The two values you gave in the last paragraph of your question are identical, so I'm not sure specifically what you were looking for.  The time you gave is indeed `1542783600`, not `1542776400`.
- [The readme file of react-datetime](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/master/README.md) describes all the options you can use.  You can simply pass the moment object obtained above to the `value` prop.   You might need to use the `utc` or `displayTimeZone` props if you want to change the behavior.  You might also need to call `.local()` or `.tz(userTimezone)` on the moment object before passing it in, but I'm not certain if that is required or not for this particular component.